# RDO Outlook Redemption access mailbox from test server

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

I've built a web app that use Redemption to read a mailbox, let's call it "custom@domain.com".  It works fine using localhost but when I deploy it I get this exception.

> > Error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005):
> >     Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
> >     {29AB7A12-B531-450E-8F7A-EA94C2F3C05F} from the IClassFactory failed
> >     due to the following error: 80004005. at
> >     System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
> >     publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
> >     RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) at
> >     System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
> >     skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) at
> >     System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
> >     Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean
> >     fillCache) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean
> >     nonPublic)

**I'm guessing my server is using its network user as the default user to logon to the mailbox, instead of the current windows NT user accessing the web app. How do I get the server or my RDO code to use the current NT user using the app with RDO?**

I have installed MAPI Extension on my server and registered the dll in the registry.

My RDO code looks like this

```
 RDOSession Session = null;
        rdoDefaultFolders olFolderInbox = rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox;

        Session = new RDOSession();//this throws the exception above
        Session.LogonExchangeMailbox("username@domain.com", outLookServer);  
         objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the code above works for the logged-on user on the same server (via RDP for example)? You need to get it to work for the logged on user in a console or winforms app before you try it from a web app.

Comment: @Ben why does this need to be tested on a winform or console before a webapp?

Comment: What is the OS bitness? What version of Outlook or MAPI did you install?

Comment: @Dmitry, the server is 64bit, the App is set to "Any CPU" which is in VS2010 MVC3 so it may default to 64...just a wild guess though. The MAPI is from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6248)

Comment: @EKet before you assume it is a problem with running in IIS, you should confirm it works *at all* on that machine. IIS adds a lot of extra considerations. I suspect component registration problem of some sort. Bitness could also be the problem as Dmitry says, so test in a 64-bit winforms app. If that works, **then** worry about IIS config.

Comment: You need to make sure your code (under IIS) is running in 32 bit to match the bitness of the MAPI system, not the OS: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Nightmare (Or not so recommended) Solution**
The problem I believe was the bitness of the application as Dmitry pointed out. However the problem with converting your apps to 32bit or 64 bit is the inevitable and horrible chain reaction of converting EVERY project in your solution to use the same bitness so that the application can use the MAPI of the same bit. If you have other apps that use the same libraries and projects then those may also break so this is easier said than done. In fact I tried it and it broke the project in so many ways...decided it wasn't worth it.

**The Best Solution**

For Exchange Server 2007_SP1 and above we have a handy WebService called Exchange Web Services MAPI that does the same thing as Redemption...maybe not as much but it does the trick for your everyday outlook needs.  Read the Guide in the download for better information.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13480

This is the best solution for me because it does not require any app to specify a bit, it does not require any special instructions and there are no loose ends. A simple DLL that does exactly what you need with authentication and even impersonation. And who doesn't like webservices?

**Sample Code**

```
using ExWs = Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data; 

 ExWs.ExchangeService service = new 
                   ExWs.ExchangeService(ExWs.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
                    service.Credentials = new   
                   ExWs.WebCredentials("username", "password", "domain");
                    service.AutodiscoverUrl("name@company.com");
```

**Tutorials**
Again read the Guide or google it.
other examples
http://omegacoder.com/?p=454
[Download attachment from Exchange using Exchange Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991301/download-attachment-from-exchange-using-exchange-web-services)

Comment: You can also wrap your MAPI related functionality into a separate exe that you can compile in both 32 and 64 bit, and then invoke it from the main executable, no matter what its bitness.