# Saving Exchange attachments to a domain obj then deleting the emails

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, ienumerable, exchangewebservices

Here's the main issue.

I'm trying to use the Repository pattern with something like this:

```
public interface IExchangeInboxRepository
{
   IEnumerable<InboxEmail> GetAllEmails();
}
```

what I want to accomplish is to grab the emails and create a Domain object like this:

```
   public class InboxEmail
   {
      public IEnumerable<FileAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
      public string FromAddress { get; set; }
      public string Subject { get; set; }
      public string Content { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateArrived { get; set; }
   }
```

The issue is that from what I can tell from trying to use EWS like in this example:

[Download attachment from Exchange using Exchange Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991301/download-attachment-from-exchange-using-exchange-web-services)

When I try and do fileAttachment.Load() on the list of Attachments in the domain obj, it's calling the Exchange service.  Not a big deal but I want the repository to delete the emails after it builds up the IEnumerable to hand back.  If I delete the emails, obviously when I try and access the FileAttachment it throws an exception that the "store is empty".  Is there a way to persist the FileAttachment?

I basically want to persist the files that are attached inside the Domain Obj, and remove the emails once they've been iterated through using EWS and return them to the user of the repository.